# Adding array into Mongodb using Mongoosejs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Here are my two schemas:

```
var itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    body    : String
});

var taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id    : { type: String, index: true }
  , short_id   : { type: String, index: true }
  , title      : { type: String, required: true }
  , desc       : String
  , items      : [itemSchema]
  , created_at : Date
});
```

From my Angularjs app I can successfully post a task (including the array of items within it) but I'm having trouble inserting the items into the db.

I am currently trying this

```
task.user_id = req.user.id;
task.short_id = '12345';
task.title = req.body.title;
task.desc = req.body.desc;
task.created_at = Date.now();
task.items.push({ body: req.body.items.body }); //note: body is also the one attribute of Item
```

and here's how I save

```
task.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return res.send(400, err)
  res.send (task)
});
```

All but the last line works - everything else gets added. How can I add the array of items into my db?

Comment: shouldn't you be using the save() function to write documents to the db? Or is that what your task.items.push() is doing?

Comment: yes just not included it above as didn't think this part was the problem. I will add it now.

Comment: Maybe this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695058/how-to-define-object-in-array-in-mongoose-schema-correctly-with-2d-geo-index

Comment: What does `req.body.items` contain?

Comment: An array: `[ { body: 'some text'},{ body: 'some more text'},{ body: 'yet more text'} ]`

Comment: perhaps I should convert it to JSON first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `req.body.items` is an array that contains items that are already in the same format as `itemSchema`, you can just assign that directly:

```
task.items = req.body.items;
```

Comment: Cheers for that - I was sure it was something simple. Thanks

Comment: Does this only work because I've called it `body` in my front-end too? If so, what would be the approach to getting this to work if I used a different attribute name?

Comment: @tommyd456 Right.  You'd need to reshape your items using something like [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if they weren't already the same.