# Node.js - Mongoose - How should I assign multiple Many-to-One relationships in this case?

Tags: mongoose

In this case, I need to assign multiple Many-to-One relationships, as you can see below:

```
var portfolioSchema = new Schema({
    volatility         :  Number,
    bonds              :  {
        percentage          :  { type: Number, default: 0.6 },
        USA                 :  {
            percentage           :  { type: Number, default: 0.7 },
            treasury             :  {
                percentage            :  { type: Number, default: 0.4 },
                securities            :  [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]
            },
            municipal            :  {
                percentage            :  { type: Number, default: 0.2 },
                securities            :  [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]
            },
            corporate            :  {
                percentage            :  { type: Number, default: 0.4 },
                securities            :  [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]
            }
        },
        international       :  {
            percentage           :  { type: Number, default: 0.3 },
            developed            :  {
                percentage            :  { type: Number, default: 0.7 },
                securities            :  [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]
            },
            emergent        :  {
                percentage            :  { type: Number, default: 0.3 },
                securities            :  [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]
            }
        }
    },
    stocks          :  {
        percentage          :  { type: Number, default: 0.4 },
        USA                 :  {
            percentage           :  { type: Number, default: 0.7 },
            largeCaps            :  {
                percentage            :  { type: Number, default: 0.4 },
                securities            :  [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]
            },
            mediumCaps           :  {
                percentage            :  { type: Number, default: 0.4 },
                securities            :  [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]
            },
            smallCaps            :  {
                percentage            :  { type: Number, default: 0.2 },
                securities            :  [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]
            }
        },
        international       :  {
            percentage           :  { type: Number, default: 0.3 },
            developed            :  {
                percentage            :  { type: Number, default: 0.7 },
                securities            :  [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]
            },
            emergent        :  {
                percentage            :  { type: Number, default: 0.3 },
                securities            :  [ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]
            }
        }
    },
    _goal           :  { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Goal' }
});

var securitySchema = new Schema({
    name               :  { type: Date, required: true },
    avgReturn          :  Number,
    avgRisk            :  Number,
    percentage         :  Number
});
```

However, It seems to me that it would be easier to simply use an `Array` data type instead of `[ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]`.

I am not sure about what I should do. Anyone would know the appropriate way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: What is `Array` data type? And why do you think it's different to `[]` data type?

Comment: I don't think it's different. My doubt is whether I should use just `Array` or `[ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you arrays are going to be only composed by your `Security` objects, you should use `[ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not write the word `Array` in mongoose schemas. Here is a relevant answer.
[How to define object in array in Mongoose schema correctly with 2d geo index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695058/how-to-define-object-in-array-in-mongoose-schema-correctly-with-2d-geo-index)

So, the short answer to your question is: Use `[ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the answer you said is relevant doesn't help me. It suggests using `Arrays` instead... Why would you suggest using `[ { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Security' } ]`? Could you please be more specific?