# Mongoose not saving array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm newbie to `mongodb` Here is my `schema`

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const SomeSchema = new Schema({

  vDocs: [{type: String , required: true,  }],
  vBelongsTo: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }

});

const SomeSchema = mongoose.model('BlaBla', SomeSchema);
export default SomeSchema;
```

mongoose is saving only simple array like  `["bla", "bla"]` in 
     `vDocs`

but I want to save something like this `[{key: val}, {key: val}]` in 
     `vDocs`
     Both are array I don't why is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define object in array in Mongoose schema correctly with 2d geo index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19701983/1207049)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `type` to be a string but you are trying to save an object

```
 //Try This
 let newObj = new SomeSchema
 newObj.vDocs = JSON.stringify(whatEverObject)
 SomeSchema.save().then(function(v){
        // whatever 
    })
```

Comment: it worked, but when I have to retrive I have to use JSON.parse()

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by changing `type: Array`. The following should work:

```js
vDocs: [{ type: Array, required: true }],
```