# Mongoose: Cast to Array failed for value "[ [ 2.3635503, 48.8674024 ]....]]"

Tags: mongoose

I met a strange question when I save position points in mongo by mongoose.

```
const testSchema1 = new mongoose.Schema({
  releasePoints: [{
    type: [Number]
  }]
}, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  }
});

const testSchema2 = new mongoose.Schema({
  releasePoints: [[Number]]
}, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  }
});
```

When I use `testSchema2` save data success, but I use `testSchema1` `throw err`:

```
validation failed: releasePoints: Cast to Array failed for value "[ [ 2.3635503,....
```

What difference about `testSchema1` and `testSchema2`?

Can add validate in `testSchema1`?

**For example:**

```
const testSchema1 = new mongoose.Schema({
  releasePoints: [{
    type: [Number],
    validate: (val) => val.length === 2
  }]
}, {
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're searching for exactly. Do you want to add a validation to your schema to verify the array length ? Do you need to solve the cast error ? Or do you need to create a schema to have an array of longitudes and latitudes ?

Comment: could you also add the insert query you make with your example ?

Answer (score 0):

from https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays you could argue that the first schema is a document array, and the 2nd one a primitive array.

from this thread
[How to define object in array in Mongoose schema correctly with 2d geo index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695058/how-to-define-object-in-array-in-mongoose-schema-correctly-with-2d-geo-index), I would say that to make the first schema to behave like the 2nd one you should write it with releasePoints like so :

```
 releasePoints: [{
    type: Array , default: []
  }]
```

then add a validator to check for "Number type insertion".
or something like:

```
releasePoints: [{
   data: [Number]
}]
```

But then you should access the value with the data attribute [x].data[y]

If you need to save a latitude/longitude value, you could simply do :

```
releasePoints: [{
   lat: Number,
   long: Number
}]
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not very skilled with comments. I update my question describtion