# make this array and store in mongodb then populate it

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, nested, populate

I want to make this type of array in mongodb

`dishes: {dish1, dish2},`

there should be multiple dishes in the dishes not just one
so output looks like

`"dishes":{ //dish one object, //dish two object, }`

how do i do that. i am using mongodb as database and nodejs as server.

Comment: In my experience you cannot save an array like that. Either you have to save it as a string  ```"dishes": "{dish1, dish2}"``` or you have to save it as an array ````"dishes":[dish1, dish2]````

Comment: so what will be the schema and will i be able to populate it and generate it from admin menu

Comment: Are you using Mongoose?

Comment: yes i am using mongoose and with nodejs. you can check the code at https://github.com/RosePinkDragon/College-Website just go to backend/models/setdishmodel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const yourSchema = new Schema({
    //Other properties,
    dishes: {
        type: [{
            dishName: {type: String},
            dishId: {type: String},
            //OtherProperties of dish object
        }],
        default: []
    },
    //Other properties
});
```

You can define your array of object like this in your schema. I hope you are using Mongoose. For more information refer Documentation and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695058/how-to-define-object-in-array-in-mongoose-schema-correctly-with-2d-geo-index).

Your data will be formated like this:

```
dishes: [
    {dishName: "dish1", dishId: "1", ... },
    {dishName: "dish2", dishId: "2", ... },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

Comment: and how do i add more from frontend see this website: food-ninjas.herokuapp.com/booking here in the set dish tab i create a predefined menu. i want to make that from frontend.

Comment: I will check and get back to you

Comment: Hey a quick update i have figured out the backend and frontend. Thanks for your help now the problem is just how do we populate it `"dishes": [
        {
          "_id": "604123ea6d7a5131a82109f2",
          "dishId": "601d1e647fab7d2090fdae99"
        }
      ],`

Comment: Heyyy i figured it all out thank you thank you thank youuuuuuu.

Comment: I am glad that you figure it out.