# Query an Array of Arrays inside of mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
const merkleTreeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    merkleTree: [
        [{
        type:String,
        required:[true,'Please Send A MekleTree'],
    }],
],
    merkleRoot:[{
        type:String,
        required:[true,'Please Send a MerkleRoot'],
    }]
},{
    timestamps:true,
},
);
```

```
MerkleTree.find({merkleTree:{$elemMatch:{hashedPdf}}});
```

have been trying to query using multiple things, it returns []
or if I just put

```
MerkleTree.find({hashedPdf});
```

it return all the documents

Comment: Here is the similar discussion about :-
[**Mongoose schema correctly with 2d index**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695058/how-to-define-object-in-array-in-mongoose-schema-correctly-with-2d-geo-index)

Comment: Thanks Man, I fixed it by breaking that array into a smaller array, so I can query it.

Comment: What was the value of `hashedPdf`? What did a sample document look like that was or wasn't getting returned?