# storing an array of objects in nextjs with mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongodb, forms, mongoose, next.js

I already have **CRUD** logic with no input array, how to implement it?

*SCHEMA:

```
const DutySchema = new mongoose.Schema<Duties>({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    location: {
        type: String,
    },
    description: [
     {"obj 1": "..."}, {"obj 2": "..."}, ...
    ]
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695058/how-to-define-object-in-array-in-mongoose-schema-correctly-with-2d-geo-index